# Add product key in already built installshield setup.exe

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Is there any way in which data can be added in already built setup made by Installshield?

What I need is to add different product keys for a same setup executable without the need to build a separate copy for each product key.

Is there any way in which this could be achieved using Installshield?

Comment: There are transforms, but whether you can realistically generate them on the fly may depend on whether you're signing your packages. Are you?

Comment: No. Can you provide some more information on the topic. I have made a research but found only tool for msi installations called Orca.

Comment: InstallShield (at least professional/premier editions) can create transforms. See File New. But more important, what are these product keys supposed to change? Does it just record a value to, say, a registry key? Does it prevent the program from working until a valid one is provided by the end user? Something else?

Comment: I need to embed a key which will probably be saved into registry until my program runs and evaluates it. Basically what I am reaching to do is :
1.Create Setup.exe
2.Send it to our client
3.The client embeds different keys in Setpu.exe 
4.The client sends different Setup.exe files with various keys to the end users.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an InstallShield setup.exe, the simplest approach is probably to also use the tool [setupini.exe](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/SetupIniExe.htm) (in some earlier versions of InstallShield this was a separate "unsupported" tool, and you can find downloads in our KB system). You could use this in a manner similar to that shown in the article, to modify the command line passed to the MSI package to include a property that contains the key. Using a property called `PRODUCTKEY` it would look like this:

```
SetupIni.exe "<path to>\MySetup.exe" Startup CmdLine PRODUCTKEY="12-34-56"
```

For this to be meaningful, you would have to include something in the installer that uses this property. The simplest may be a registry key whose value (or value data) includes a reference to the `PRODUCTKEY` property. Represented as a .reg file, that might look like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\My Company Name\My Product Name\Version]
"ProductKey"="[PRODUCTKEY]"
```

Note that `PRODUCTKEY` should be a public property (its name includes no lower case characters), and listed in the `SecureCustomProperties` property. Note as well that this should be considered advisory rather than secure: if, for example, you are looking to license your product by requiring the customer to enter a matching code, don't. This approach makes the key available to customers with the know-how to log the installation, or even to find command-lines with task manager.

If setting a property is insufficient for your needs, you could also consider [creating a transform](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpTransforms.htm), and configuring it to apply automatically through the use of setupini.exe, but then you will also have the problem of getting the transform to the customer since he probably downloads only a single file today, and this would require two files.

Comment: I understood how this should work. However Installshield does not allow me to create a new registry key in the registry view. On the "Destination Computer" no context menu is shown on right click. Sadly in this moment I'm using Installshield 10.5 Premier edition.
Can you help me out with this issue?

Comment: No clue why that wouldn't work (are you right clicking in the right place?), but you should be able to get the same effect by using the direct editor. Add a component, if necessary, and then add a row to the Registry table. The syntax is straightforward.